# Audit Log not working until check-out/-in (SharePoint 2010)

Tags: sharepoint-server, auditing

We have one very strange problem with audit logs on document library. When a user with Contribute permission creates a document audit log does not start loging the new document until SiteCollection administrator check-outs (and then undo check-out) it.

If a SiteCollection administrator creates new document Audit log works as it should. This problem is present on only one document library.

Do you have any ideas how to solve this problem?